# Unable to start Amazon Lambda on the command line (HelloWorld example)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I followed Amazon's tutorials on creating a HelloWorld lambda function in the Sydney region. It worked on the AWS console.

[image]

Then I tried to do it on the command line:

> aws lambda invoke --invocation-type RequestResponse --function-name HelloWorld --region Sydney --payload '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}' outputfile.txt

Error:

> Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://lambda.Sydney.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/HelloWorld/invocations"

I think my security keys are working because the the following command for listing my S3 buckets worked:

> aws s3api list-buckets # Worked, so the security keys should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the CLI command you issued to invoke the Lambda function, it seems like the issue lies in the region parameter.

Instead of the region parameter value "**Sydney**", replace it with "**ap-southeast-2**" which is the regional code for Asia Pacific (Sydney).